# How to read in sqlite3 file into chunks to transform into csv file python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I want to convert a table stored in a .sqlite3 file into a csv file using python. Currently I use the following code for it

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
con = sqlite3.connect(FILE_PATH)
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", con)
```

However, for the last command I get a `MemoryError`. Does anyone know a way how to do this. Perhaps reading in the data in chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect(FILE_PATH, isolation_level=None,
                       detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", con)
df.to_csv('database.csv', index=False)
```

This would create a csv file with the table and its respective values.